# Substrate Node compiles, but does not run

Tags: compilation

When i run my substrate based node, i get `Error: Service(Client(VersionInvalid("host doesn't provide any imports from non-env module: __wbindgen_placeholder__:__wbindgen_describe")))`.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) otherwise it is very hard for us to debug.